# Trying to make a login program

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a login page. When the program starts, the user has to type `Guest` and Password `1234` and he can edit his/her account. However, when I try to run it, it says:

```
Line 15 "Error incompatible types in assignment of 'const char[6]' to 'char[20]'
Line 16 "Error incompatible types in assignment of 'const char[5]' to 'char[20]'
```

I think it has to do with pointers but I am still a c++ newbie so I am having a hard time to understand pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

const int LINE_LENGTH=20;
const int ID_LENGTH=8;
struct profile{char user[20];char password[20];double CGPA; int ID;};


int main(){
int count=0, i;
profile student[10];
student[0].user="Guest"; //Line 15
student[0].password="1234"; //Line 15
char signupName[20];
char signupPassword[20];
while (count==0)
{
cout << "#############################################\n";
cout << "           Welcome to my program!        \n";
cout << "         Sign up to get started      \n\n\n";
cout << "   If you are starting, use username 'Guest'        \n";
cout << "            and password '1234'        \n\n";
cout << "Username: ";
cin >> signupName;
cout << "Password: ";
cin >> signupPassword;
cout << "#############################################\n";
for (i=0;i<11; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(signupName,student[i].user)==0 && strcmp(student[i].password,signupPassword)==0)
    {
            count++;
    }

}
    if(count==0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Your username and/or password is incorrect\n";
    }
}
system("cls");
}
```

Comment: `student[0].user=="Guest";` is a comparison. It's the same as writing `i == 10;` where `i` is an `int`.

Comment: You can't assign a string literal directly. Use `std::string` instead of `char[]`s.

Comment: How does this even compile?

Comment: I put the errors when I compiled it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Originally, it apparently did: "_However, when I type "Guest", and then "1234" for the password, it says it is incorrect_". Moving goalposts: wonderful for everyone.

Comment: With the (presumably pre-edit) `student[0].user=="Guest";` version, it does compile (but obviously doesn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two minor changes to your code! First, as Francois Andrieux says, you can't assign char array strings with = ...

```
//  student[0].user = "Guest";
//  student[0].password = "1234";
    strcpy(student[0].user, "Guest");
    strcpy(student[0].password, "1234");
```

Second, your `for` loop runs once to often:

```
//  for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Note: The last element in an array of 10 is x[9]!
```